# prove or show false - integrals

Tags: integration

I ran into a question that I'm not really sure how to solve:

Prove or show false:

for every $\;y\geqslant x\geqslant 0\;$ :

$$\int_{x}^{\infty}(e^{-y^2/2})dy\leqslant \int_{x}^{\infty}(y/x)(e^{-y^2/2})dy$$

Thank you very muck in advance,

Yaron

Comment: Check the FAQ section for directions how to use LaTeX in this site.

Answer (score 2):

In the right integral, what can you say about $\frac{y}{x}$ in the integrand?

And in general, if $f\geq g$ are both in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$, what can you say about $\int_\mathbb{R} f$ compared to $\int_\mathbb{R} g$?

Comment: Incidentally, I think that "$x>0$" would make more sense (the RHS is not defined for $x=0$)